# Issue with simple Javascript executing correctly

Tags: javascript

Good morning all, and please go easy as this is my first post.  I have a simple data entry form on our Intranet site, and on 2 of the fields I am trying to use JavaScript to simply validate a "if this then that" scenario.

The code below which I will call block 1 and block 2, each work individually.  i.e if I leave only block 1 of the JavaScript in place it validates the fields exactly as it should.  If I leave only block 2 of the code in place, it validates the fields it's supposed to exactly as it should.  If I leave both block 1 and block 2 of the code in place, block 1 will validate the fields as it should and block 2 simply gets skipped.

This should be very simple, yet I don't see what I am missing.   Thanks in advance for the help and again, individually each block works correctly.

(block 1)

```
// checks to ensure that Payroll Deduction field is populated correctly
    if((document.getElementById('yespayroll').checked) && (document.order.payamount.value==""))
    {
        alert("Please enter the Amount for payroll deduction.");
        document.order.payamount.focus();
        return false;
    }

    else if ((document.getElementById('nopayroll').checked) && (document.order.payamount.value!==""))
    {
        alert("Please remove the Payroll deduction amount");
        document.order.payamount.focus();
        return false;
    }

    {
        return true;

    }
```

(block 2)

```
// checks to ensure that both the Gift Card and Amount are entered or that both are set to none
    if((document.order.giftcard.value!=="None") && (document.order.amount.value=="None"))
    {
        alert("Please enter the AMOUNT for your selected Gift Card.");
        document.order.amount.focus();
        return false;
    }

    else if((document.order.giftcard.value=="None") && (document.order.amount.value!=="None"))
    {
        alert("Please select a Gift Card for the selected Amount.");
        return false;
    }

    else

    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Are both code blocks contained in the same `if`?

Comment: Hi. "return" statement means "end of function".  On first return (in block 1) you leave your code and block 2 is not reached.

Comment: Total brain fart.  Removing "return true;" took care of the issue.   Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because block1 is returning false.

Try setting a flag to keep track of the errors and return false at the bottom of the function:

```
var has_errors = false;

// if block1 has errors set has_errors to true
// if block2 has errors set has_errors to true

if (has_errors) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Return" statement means "end of function". On first return (in block 1) you leave your code and block 2 is not reached. This is possible variant to solve your issue.

```
var isValid = true;

// block 1
if ( ... ) {
    // alert and code
    isValid = false;
}
// block 2
if ( ... ) {
    // alert and code
    isValid = false;
}
return isValid;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please put at least one explanatory line on top of your Cod.e and ensure its either your intellectual work or is cited properly

Comment: I thought it is obvious. Also I've already commenting this answer, just want to add some code example. But you're right, thanks!